# Why the syntax for defining sigils in Elixir doesn't use "defsigil"?

Tags: elixir, sigils

I was reading the [page](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html) about sigils in the Elixir tutorial.
I expected the syntax for defining sigils uses "defsigil" just like "defstruct", "defprotocol", and so on.
But it was not so.
Why?

Comment: Question seems more appropriate to ask to the core Elixir maintainers than here.  Vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original sigil syntax was `def __s__` where `s` is the character used for the sigil (this would now be `def sigil_s`.) You can see this in the [initial commit](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/c3e4e968e22a28689802972a75aaf5a0ac3cd7f9) that started work on sigils. I believe this work started before macros were implemented.

This syntax required a hack to allow them to be imported which you can read about in [this issue.](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/1301)

> Today, when someone writes %f"foo", it translates to **f**("foo", []). This proposal is to change the translation to: sigil_f("foo", []).
>
> This change brings two benefits:
>
> 1) The name is more explicit;
>   2) It allows us to remove a hack in our importer. Today, import Hello brings all functions from Hello that do not start with underscore but it makes an exception for sigils;

You can see in the discussion that some other suggestions such as `defmodule Sigil.s` were suggested, however the `def sigil_s` syntax was ultimately chosen.

The actual commit that implements these changes is https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/c6284557e792efd67f13f421b723a7a301bdbb93

I am not sure why it is not `defsigil` perhaps nobody suggested it? This is my best guess given that at the time of this post, searching for "defsigil" on [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22defsigil%22) only returns this question. If it was mentioned on GitHub or IRC then there would have been a mention of it in the search results.

Answer (score 3):

Sigils are just a fancy way to call specific methods. Take a look at  the section on [Custom Sigils](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#custom-sigils). Basically `~x/things/options` is the same as `sigil_x(things, options)`. So you can write something like:

```
defmodule Thing do
  def sigil_u(string, _options) do
    string |> String.upcase
  end

  def test do
    ~u/bob/
  end
end

IO.inspect Thing.test
```

Comment: I would also argue that there's a "moral" reason why `defsigil` does not exist: sigils can lead to extremely cryptic code very quickly. Elixir gives the tools to write custom sigils, but I think they should be used only where the benefits of using them are *a lot*.

Comment: But I want to know the reason why it isn't `defsigil u(string, _options) do string |> String.upcase end`.

Comment: You'd have to ask Jose directly - best place for that is probably #elixir-lang on freenode IRC.